# Getting error Cannot convert value of type '(String,_) -> String' to expected argument type '(_, String) -> _'

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get the sum of all the values inside of my array "reviewArray". After looking for things online I set up self.reviewArray.reduce, but I get the error and i'm not too sure of what exactly to do "Cannot convert value of type '(String,*) -> String' to expected argument type '(*, String) -> _'" how can I go about fixing this?

This is is my code

```
var reviewArray = [String]()
func testForGettingAllValues(){
 let uid = user2?.id
    let ref =  FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("userRating").child(uid!)
        ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "ratingNumber").observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in
            if snapshot.exists(){
                if let values = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
                    for reviews in values {
                        if let userReviews =  reviews.value["ratingNumber"] as? String{
                            self.reviewArray.append(userReviews)
                                print("this is to check what is inside  of the array", self.reviewArray)

//This is where i'm trying to find the sum of all the values inside of my array
                                    var ratingSum =  self.reviewArray.reduce(0,{$0 + $1})


                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `reviewArray` is `[String]`, so you need to convert the rating to a `Double`:

```
var ratingSum = self.reviewArray.reduce(0, {$0 + (Double($1) ?? 0)})
```

Since the `String` might not convert to a `Double`, I've used the *nil coalescing operator* `??` to use `0` in that case.

---

Alternatively, you could convert the array to `[Double]` first using `flatMap` to remove values that didn't convert to `Double` and then use `reduce`:

```
var ratingSum = self.reviewArray.flatMap { Double($0) }.reduce(0, +)
```

---

If your ratings are integer values, just use `Int` instead of `Double` above.

---

If your strings have leading and trailing whitespace, you will need to remove that before converting to `Double`:

```
Double($0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)) ?? 0
```

Comment: it's coming up with "0" so i'm guessing that my string isn't converting to an Int, is there anything else I can provide? @vacawama

Comment: You might need to trim leading and trailing spaces before converting to `Int`.

Comment: Could you do `self.reviewArray.forEach { print("***\($0)***") }` to see what your array looks like? Put no spaces between the `***` and the number.

Comment: Alright this is what printed out                                                                      *** 4.50 ***
*** 4.50 ***

Comment: OK, you have floating point values, so you'll need to use `Double` instead of `Int`.  Are those spaces next to the numbers in your print string, or are they really in the array?

Comment: Changing it from Int to Double did the trick! I appreciate the help

Comment: Great!.  I added info on trimming whitespace as well.  You didn't need it, but someone else might.